# ubuntu 14.04 resolution and mouse messed up

Tags: 14.04, networking, graphics, mouse

Yesterday night when I closed my computer everything was working fine but when I booted it up this morning everything was messed up.My screen resolution was set to very low, my mouse was not working and I was unable to connect to the internet.

The weird thing is i did nothing out of ordinary to cause this problem.
I have a dual boot pc with windows 7 which is working fine so I think its not a hardware problem. Can anyone help?
UPDATE:
After searching around a bit I found out that I face this problem when booting ubuntu with linux 3.13.0-46 while everything is fine when booting with kernel 3.13.0-45. I still haven't found a solution though

Comment: Please tell what type of PC ie, laptop, desktop, tablet and what type of GPU, what was the last thing you did before shutting down your PC ?

Comment: Its a desktop.please read the update

Answer (score 0):

Install this update then boot to 3.13.0-47 and see if it fixes the issue http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/trusty/main/base/linux-image-3.13.0-47-generic

Answer (score 0):

In the Grub boot menu select `Advanced Settings for Ubuntu`

In there you will see a list of alternatives, try a different one.

If it works alright, make sure to:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`